# How to pass string with double quotes as command line parameter to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to pass a string seperated with spaces using double quotes as the command line parameter to the batch file. But only first word is taken and remaining are ignored. Below is my batch file.

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" (
    echo "Usage: filename <interface_name>"
    exit /B ) 
set INTERFACE=%1
echo "Going to execute build for %INTERFACE%
```

Executing the above batch script results in the below error output.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\HPFW>save.bat "Ethernet PCIe Adapter"
PCIe was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\HPFW>
```

Can anybody please let me know how do we handle string separated with double quotes when passed as command line parameter to the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "%~1" == "" (
```

This removes any enclosing quotes from `%1`, then makes sure the quotes exist for the comparison.

Another way would be

```
set "INTERFACE=%~1"
if not defined interface (error message etc)
```

where the value of `interface` is set to (first parameter - enclosing quotes). The quotes here ensure trailing spaces on the command line are not included in the value assigned.

If then `interface` is not defined (as the parameter is missing) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can dequote the command line arguments (and for tokens with `~`):

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" (
    echo "Usage: filename <interface_name>"
    exit /B ) 
set "INTERFACE=%~1"
echo "Going to execute build for '%INTERFACE%'"
```